Error during playing youtube video in Video.js,React
I get an error when I try to mute video in Video.js. The YouTube player is not attached to the DOM. API calls should be made after the onReady event.
export default function VideoJSPlayer({
  options,
  onReady,
}: {
  options: any;
  onReady: (player: Player) => void;
}) {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const playerRef = useRef<Player | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleReady = () => {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      if (player) {
        // Mute the player after it's ready
        player.muted(true);
      }
    };

    if (!playerRef.current) {
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video");

      videoRef.current?.appendChild(videoElement);
      const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        onReady && onReady(player);
      }));

      // Listen for the 'ready' event
      player.on("ready", handleReady);
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.width(options.width);
      player.height(options.height);
    }

    return () => {
      if (playerRef.current && !playerRef.current.isDisposed()) {
        playerRef.current.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [options, videoRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <div ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
<VideoJSPlayer
       options={{
         loop: true,
         muted: true,
         autoplay: true,
         controls: false,
         responsive: true,
         fluid: true,
         techOrder: ["youtube"],
         sources: [
          {
           type: youtubeType,
           src: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3oOldViIgY",
           }       
      ],
  }}
 onReady={handleReady}

in the tutorial every thing is going good, same versions ,
the errors are: www-widgetapi.js:1275 The YouTube player is not attached to the DOM. API calls should be made after the onReady event,
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:5173')
